# Showing the Closed unit disk is not open but is closed and perfect - metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to show that the closed unit disk i.e. $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 1\}$ is closed and perfect but it is not open.

I have managed to show that it is closed (I think) but am unsure of my final step.

Showing it is Closed:

Consider $D^{c} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| >1\}$ and let $z_{0} \in D^{c}, |z_{0}| = 1+r, r > 0.$ Then if we consider $B_{r}(z_{0}) = \{w \in \mathbb{C} : |z_{0} - w| < r\}$

By the triangle inequality I get $|z_{0}| \leq |z_{0} - w| + |w| \Rightarrow |w| \geq |z_{0}| - |z_{0} - w| = 1+r - r = 1$. Therefore $|w| \in D^{c}.$ Can I then say that $B_{r}(z_{0}) \subseteq D^{c}$. Hence $D^{c}$ is open and $D$ is closed.

Questions on the above:

1. I believe that equality at the end of the triangle inequality argument by $ >$ but I can't see why?
2. Can I make the argument that just because $|w| \in D^{c}$ then the ball is contained in $D^{c}$

Showing it is not Open:

I was trying to do this directly. Take $(v,w) \in D$ and let $\epsilon = 1 - \sqrt{v^{2} + w^{2}}$ then if $(s,t) \in B_{\epsilon}((v,w))$ we have that $d((s,t), (0,0)) \leq d((s,t), (v,w)) + d((v,w), (0,0)).$ But this doesn't seem correct to me, as after doing the calculations I get that the set is open.

Showing it is Perfect:

Rudin defines a Perfect set as one that is closed and every point in the set is a limit point. I only need to check that every point is a limit point, as I've shown the set is closed.

I am stuck here as well. I choose a point $w \in D$ and let $r > 0.$ Now we need to show if we draw a ball with radius $r$ center $w$ that we get a point that is different to $w.$

$B_{r}(w) = \{v \in \mathbb{C} : |w - v| \leq r\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to proving $D^c$ is open. Just notice there that you have mistakenly put the equal sign here $|w|\ge |z_0|-|z_0-w|\gt 1+r-r=1$ since $(|z_0-w|\lt r)$

Showing it is not open is trivial. Take a point on the boundary,let us say $z_0$, then $|z_0|=1$ . For every $\epsilon \gt 0$, consider the neighbourhood $B(z_0,\epsilon)$ .Then $B(z_0,\epsilon)\cap D^c\neq \emptyset$   ( By definition of the boundary point ).

This shows
$B(z_0,\epsilon) \nsubseteq D$.Hence $z_0$ is not interior point.

Now $D\subset D'$(the set of limit points of $D$) , since the points in $D$ are either interior points or boundary points. To show it is perfect, we just have to show there is no limit point of $D$ in $D^c$, which is easy since every point in $D^c$ is interior and $ D\cap D^c=\emptyset$. So no neighbourhood of a point in $D^c$ contains a point of $D$. Thus proving the claim.

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed response. I'm understanding everything apart from, on the perfect sets Why is $D \subset D'$.? Is it because D is closed, it must contain all of its limit points? We know every point in $D^{c}$ is interior since it is an open set?

Comment: No, $D\subset D'$  because every point of $D$ except the points at boundary i.e $D\setminus \partial D$ is interior and every interior point of a set is a limit point of the set. Similarly , the points of the boundary $D$ are limit points because every deleted neighbourhood of such a point has a non-empty intersection with the set $D$ ,by definition.The fact that $D$ is closed just helps in claiming that there no limit point outside of $D$, i.e in $D^c$.(so that part of my answer was unnecessary). And yes every point in $D^c$ is interior since it is open.Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For your (1) you had $|w| \geq |z_o| - |z_0 - w|$ and you assumed $|z_0 - w| < r$. Hence $-|z_0 - w| > -r$ and $|w| \geq |z_o| - |z_0 - w| > r + 1 - r = 1$.

For (2) remember that you were trying to show that $w \in D^c$. You correctly noted that $D^c = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| > 1\}$, and this is exactly what you showed, |w| > 1.

For non-openness think about the boundary points on $D$ (namely any point on the circle of radius 1) and try to derive a contradiction.

For perfectness you need to construct a sequence of points in $D$ getting arbitrarily close to any given $z \in D$. A hint is to consider a sequence of points converging to $z$ along the line from the origin to $z$.

Comment: Thanks the tips. I will have a think and post an edit if I make any progress!

Comment: @Mathlearner just remember that all of these things are very geometric and it really helps if you draw some pretty pictures of what you're trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

**Closed:** Note $|z_0-w| <r \implies -|z_0-w|>-r.$ Therefore $|w|>|z_0|-r=1+r-r=1.$

**Not open:** You want to show $\exists\; z\in D$ such that $B_r(z)\not\subseteq D$ for every $r >0.$ Consider $z=1 \in D$ and $r>0$ be arbitrary. Show that $1-\frac{r}{4} \in B_r(z) \cap D$ and $1-\frac{r}{4} \in B_r(z) \cap D^c.$

**Perfect:** Let $z \in D, r>0.$ You want to show $\exists\; w \in D$ such that $0<|w-z|<r.$

If $r\geq1,$ then you can in fact pick any point of $D$ different from $z.$ If $r<1,$ show $w=z+\frac{r}{2}$ is one such point.